# Best practice to pass data from Laravel to Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

> This is my blade code

```
<div id="app">
  <Testcomponent bam-wam="ham" />
</div>
```

> This is my VueJS Component code

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "ExampleComponent",
        props: [
            'bamWam'
        ],
        data () {
            return {

            };
        },
        created() {
            console.log(this.bamWam);
        }
    }
</script>
```

> Question is

This code runs good but I am asking what is better **using Axios and Vuex to fetch data from my Laravel app** or simply **Pass data throw props like I did in this code**?

Comment: Either works, it really depends on the use case.  If you're using Laravel to generate all the views and just have vue components spread out across the project, then this implementation is probably fine.  If you're trying to build an entire frontend or SPA out of vue and using Laravel more as a backend API, then use AJAX for everything.

Comment: Thank you that is helpful.. You could post it as an answer

Comment: it's not really an answer, it's just my opinion.  Best practice / opinionated questions and answers are discouraged here.  I'm glad I could help, I'd probably just delete this question though.

Answer (score 38):

**Pass data through props** is the best way.

```
<my-component my-data="yourData"></my-component>
```

If you want to use **laravel** variable for data from blade then,

```
<my-component my-data="'{{ $data->id }}'"></my-component>

<my-component :my-data="'{!! json_encode($data) !!}'"></my-component>
```

Avoid api call as much as possible. It will reduce the total number of request to server and expose fewer number of api endpoint.

Comment: who gave this fellow a vote down? This should be accepted as the answer. Not perfect, but it's a way to get the job done.

Comment: If you see your data begin displayed instead of being sent to your component, try using `:my-data="{{ json_encode($data) }}"` [source](https://www.spicydog.org/blog/passing-variable-laravel-vuejs-2-component/)

Answer (score 8):

If the data is available to the view where the component is added. Then the best way to pass php arrays from laravel to a vue component is to utilize json encoding like so:

```
<my-component :needed-data='@json($laravelCollection)'></my-component>
```

This will make you will be easily to perform actions to the php array in the Vue controller as if it was a JS object. Keep in mind that you have to use single quotes for `@json`.

For simple strings you can just directly pass it as props without the encoding.

This approach is better than creating a new API specifically for this component.

Answer (score 4):

This was the only way that works for me:

```
<my-component :data="{{ $collection }}"></my-component>
```

JSON parsed solutions prints data in HTML.