# How to stop calculation on Vue Component Props in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use laravel and Vue.

My blade in laravel has these input variables.

```
$sdate // value = "2020-01-01"
$edate
```

There is a Vue component in that blade:

```
<my-component :sdate="{{$sdate}}" :edate="{{$edate}}"></my-component>
```

As you see above, I pass data to component but the value I get in Vue is 2018. it's the calculation of my string.

```
2018 = 2020-1-1
```

How to stop calculation on input?

Answer (score 0):

The correct form of passing data to Vue Component is:

```
<my-component sdate="{{$sdate}}" edate="{{$edate}}"></my-component>
```

No need to Collon(:) before prop names.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397411/4031505