# How to show count in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am first time working on vue.js. I am trying to show the total count of data on my dashboard.
here is my controller :

```
public function dashboardData () {
    $data['totalproducts'] = Products::count();
    return $this->setStatusCode(200)->respondWithSuccess('OK', 'data', 'Data Loaded Successfully', $data);
}
```

When I dd($data); I can see the data count in console,

I have tried `{{ $data['totalproducts'] }}` to show the data in dashboard.vue but I don't understand why its not showing the the count,

Any suggestions please....

Comment: How you receiving data on vue file share your vue code

Comment: when I dd($data), I can see the data in console.

Comment: Pass your data through props <my-comp my-data="data"></my-comp>

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366437/best-practice-to-pass-data-from-laravel-to-vue-component